# How to collect and record the user's interact process in iOS app and export as video, but without using screen recording

Tags: ios, screen, screen-recording

Screen recording will generate a huge data byte and have a lot of limitation when using. I want to record screen by myself without using Apple's screen recording API. Is there a solution or a related blog to reference.

Comment: Have you looked into third-party analytics tools like AppsFlyer? I remember using them in some of my past projects, and the quality of recording was configurable. (However, probably the screen is recorded in high quality and the video transcoded into lower quality before sending, I don't know). You can also consider events driven analytics, which are obviously more lightweight and very flexible in configuring the amount of data you need.

Comment: Could you please clarify your goal, and what kind of limitations do you have in mind when talking about the screen recording?